# Ruby Gem OAuth 1.0 Fails to Authorize in Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, oauth, rubygems, flickr

I am using the Ruby Oauth 1.0 library in my script (non-rails) that calls a Flickr 3rd party API which needs authorization.  I have been having trouble getting the authorization of my request token.  I continually get back 401 Unauthorized.  My confusion stems from the use of callbacks, session and redirects being used in a ruby script.  How is this supposed to work in a regular Ruby script that is not in itself a webserver/rails app?  I have gotten the authentication to work manually in Postman but in order to get the authorization verifier, I have to open a browser and paste the callback as the URL and then copy the verifier that appears in the URL.

I would seem that since I am not authenticating at a website that the callback, redirect_to and session would not be needed.

Is there a way to get this working in my script without a callback and redirect?

I tried the following with the results included.

A snippet is listed below of what I'm trying to do.

```
require 'oauth'
require 'byebug'

callback_url = "localhost URL"

# Create a new OAuth::Consumer instance by passing it a configuration hash:
consumer_key = "a2e299ac1d635a7c9f2d7c7b70588679"
consumer_secret = "235de478b9a078ae"

@oauth_consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, 
    {   :site => "https://flickr.com",
        # {   :site => "https://flickr.com/services",
        :scheme             => :header,
        :http_method        => :get,
        :request_token_path => "request_token URL",
        :access_token_path  => "access_token URL",
        :authorize_path     => "authorize URL",
        :body_hash_enabled  => false,
        :debug_output       => true
             })
@request_token = @oauth_consumer.get_request_token(oauth_callback: callback_url)
session = {}
session[:token] = @request_token
session[:token_secret] = @request_token
# redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url(oauth_callback: callback_url) # redirect_to not available in ruby script

puts "request token: #{session[:token]}"
puts "request token secret: #{session[:token_secret]}"
auth_str = @request_token.authorize_url(oauth_callback: callback_url)

# When user returns create an access_token
hash = { oauth_token: session[:token], oauth_token_secret: session[:token_secret] }
@request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.from_hash(@oauth_consumer, hash)

@access_token = @request_token.get_access_token
@recognitions = @access_token.get("login URL")
type here
```

I see the following results.

```
reading 28 bytes...
-> "oauth_problem=token_rejected"
read 28 bytes
Conn close
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from flickr_client.rb:38:in `<main>'
        1: from /Users/bhunsake/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/oauth-1.1.0/lib/oauth/tokens/request_token.rb:28:in `get_access_token'
/Users/bhunsake/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/oauth-1.1.0/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:268:in `token_request': 401 Unauthorized (OAuth::Unauthorized)
```

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and we're well past the point where we need to use the clunky Ruby 1.8 hash notation. Here `scheme: :header` and so on look more succinct and match the prevailing styles used in Python and JavaScript, among others.

Comment: Often there's a reason given for the rejection. Can you find that?

Comment: @tadman thank you for your feedback on old ruby notation.  There was not a specific reason given for the rejection.  I have found what I was looking for though in getting this to work.  See answer below.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific use-case, the work I've done is often through another wrapper like Devise, but when OAuth fails it usually gives you some kind of hint as to why. Expired token, incorrect somethingorother, there's a message associated with the rejection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple answer to my own question. Apparently the Ruby Auth Consumer object takes care of any authorization/authentication when no login verification is needed.  In this case with Flickr, I just needed to add the Consumer (API) Key as shown below.

```html
require 'oauth'

consumer_key = "a2e299ac1d635a7c9f2d7c7b70588679"
consumer_secret = "235de478b9a078ae"
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, 
    :site => "https://www.flickr.com/services")

response = consumer.request(:get, '/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=a2e299ac1d635a7c9f2d7c7b70588679&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1', nil, {}, {})
puts response.body
```